# Enabling changing value of an class instance attribute marked as 'attr_reader'

Tags: ruby, oop, constructor, encapsulation, nomethoderror

I have the following code:

```
class A
   attr_reader :x, :y

   private_class_method :new

   def self.with_data
     a = new
     a.x = 2
     a.y = 'sid'
     a
   end
 end
```

The intent is to restrict changing values of `x` and `y` variables once the class is initialized through the factory method `with_data`.  However, I want this to be allowed when the object is initialized from within the class, as evident from the code above.

But I am getting the following error when I invoke `obj = A.with_data`:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `x='

Should't this be allowed from inside class?  Do I need to define `attr_writer` for this?  That would jeopardize encapsulation.

Also, I don't want to define a private setter method for each attribute in the class, as it might run into upto 30 instance level variables.  Does ruby provide any feature to get around this?

**Versions**:
Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Why don't you just set the instance variable in the `initialize` method? Why the extra `with_data` factory method? What do you try to achieve that cannot be done in `initialize`? If `initialize` was the only method assigning values to the variables, they cannot easily change later on. Do I miss something?

Comment: @spickermann I have put here just the minimum required code.  I will have multiple factory methods in my actual class.  Hence the factory method.

Comment: @Sid: you say you don't want to "jeopardize encapsulation". But you also want to manipulate the internal state of `a` from `A`. Now, `a` and `A` are two *completely different* objects, they don't have the same *class*, `a` is an instance of `A`, `A` is an instance of `Class`! So, you say you want to set `a`'s internal state from `A`, which is a completely different object. But, setting an object's internal state from a *different* object is pretty much the *definition* of an encapsulation violation. You can't have it both ways: either you allow `a`'s internal state to be manipulated from a …

Comment: …third-party object (such as `A`), or you don't. (Technically speaking, you can *always* violate encapsulation using reflection methods such as `send`, `instance_variable_set` and friends.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need in your case is [Object#`instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set):

```
class A
  attr_reader :x, :y

  private_class_method :new

  def self.with_data
    a = new
    a.instance_variable_set(:@x, 2)
    a.instance_variable_set(:@y, 'sid')
    a
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
a = A.with_data
#=> #<A:0x007ff37c979d30 @x=2, @y="sid">
a.x
#=> 2
a.x = 3
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `x=' for #<A:0x007ff37c979d30 @x=2, @y="sid">
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  I hope the performance is not bad with the dynamic method.

Comment: @Sid no probs. Do not forget to select and accept answer to your questions if there is one that solves it.

Comment: Yep, I will give another day if someone else replies.  Then accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sid no rush at all. Just a reminder about other questions as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, `attr_reader` will only define a getter, so you can use accessors inside the class either.

That said, what exactly are you trying to achieve? The following class will initialize attributes, expose them via a reader and not make them easily changeable from "outside". Isn't that just what you wanted to to?

```
class A
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def initialize
    @x = 2
    @y = 'sid'
  end 
end
```

Comment: I am sorry if the intent was not clear from my code. I don't want to expose the constructor and enable object creation only through factory methods, as in my actual code it's quite a complex object with multiple factory methods. Does this help clear my intent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "don't want to expose the constructor and enable object creation only through factory methods". Ruby *doesn't have* constructors, *all* object creation is *always* done only through factory methods (with the exception of `true`, `false`, `nil`, `Float`, `Integer`, `Rational`, `Complex`, `Symbol`, `String`, `Array`, `Hash`, and lambda literals, of course).

Comment: By constructor I mean the `initialize` method.  I don't want to expose it so that the instance is created through it.  I want factory methods to create instances of those.

Comment: `initialize` is not a constructor, it is an initializer. (Well, actually, it's just a method like every other method.) "I don't want to expose it so that the instance is created through it." – I don't understand. First off, instances are created with `Class#allocate`, not `initialize`; after all, `initialize` is an instance method, IOW it is called on an *existing instance*, so it is logically impossible for it to create the instance. And secondly, what do you mean by "expose"? `initialize` is `private` by default, unless you explicitly make it `public` or `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

> The intent is to restrict changing values of `x` and `y` variables once
>   the class is initialized through the factory method `with_data`

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar, :baz # <==== assures you only read, not write

  def initialize
    @bar = :bar
    @baz = :baz
  end
end
```

Now you can only read attributes, not write them:

```
foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007ff6148f0a90 @bar=:bar, @baz=:baz>
foo.bar
#=> :bar
foo.bar = 2
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `bar=' for #<Foo:0x007ff6148f0a90 @bar=:bar, @baz=:baz
```

Comment: I am sorry if the intent was not clear from my code.  I don't want to expose the constructor and enable object creation only through factory methods, as in my actual code it's quite a complex object with multiple factory methods.  Does this help clear my intent?

Comment: @Sid I added another answer, but I still don't see how it's better than this answer. Anyway.. :)

Comment: I understand that in the context of the code posted above, any other solution might seem like an overkill.  But imagine a class which acts as a data container that has 30+ instance variables.  I want to initialize those instance variables differently for different cases, but not expose that logic to calling methods.  Hence different factory methods.  That would require having a private constructor and only reader methods.  But, unlike Java, Ruby does not enable setting values even from within the class.  Hence the conundrum.  If there's a better way to achieve this, I am more than glad to hear

Comment: I get the feeling that your actual conundrum may be that you're trying to replicate something Java-like in Ruby. If you're fighting the language to achieve what you want, it may be time to reconsider if your approach is idiomatic. But since you never described the actual problem, no one here will be able to help you. Good luck with the `instance_varible_set` approach.

Comment: @Sid: "Ruby does not enable setting values even from within the class" – I have no idea what you mean by that. I mean, instance variables would be pretty darn useless if Ruby didn't allow you to set them!

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I don't understand your adversity for using `initialize` or an `attr_writer`. I feel the cleanest solution for when you have only one factory method is to use the standard name for factory methods in Ruby, namely `new`:

```
class A
   attr_reader :x, :y

   def initialize(x, y) self.x, self.y = x, y end

   def self.new
     super(2, 'sid')
   end

   private

   attr_writer :x, :y
 end
```

If you have multiple factory methods and want to make absolutely sure that nobody accidentally calls `new`, this is a good solution:

```
class A
   attr_reader :x, :y

   def initialize(x, y) self.x, self.y = x, y end

   private_class_method :new

   def self.with_data
     new(2, 'sid')
   end

   private

   attr_writer :x, :y
 end
```

If you really, really, really must, you can replicate what `new` is doing in your factory methods. After all, the implementation of `new` is quite trivial:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.__send__(:initialize, *args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```